# Tabs not visible but navigation on swipe works in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tablayout

I am trying to create an app with 3 simple tabs using tabbed activity. I created a project with tabbed activity then I removed the auto generated static Fragment class and created 3 fragment classes as well as fragment layouts and used them in FragmentPagerAdapter.
Tabs are working, I can swipe between the tabs, but I am **not able to see the TAB headers on the top.**
Any suggestion ?

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.kbsoft.tabbedtest;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Tab1();
                case 1:
                    return new Tab2();
                case 2:
                    return new Tab3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "TAB 1";
                case 1:
                    return "TAB 2";
                case 2:
                    return "TAB 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.kbsoft.tabbedtest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Tab1.java**

```
package com.kbsoft.tabbedtest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kbsoft.tabbedtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All other fragment classes and fragment layouts are identical.

Comment: You don't have any tabs anywhere. A `ViewPager` doesn't automatically come with tabs. You could add a `TabLayout` to your layout, and use the `setupWithViewPager()` method to generate a tab for each page in the `Adapter`. This looks to be what you meant to do, since you've implemented a `getPageTitle()` method in the `Adapter`.

Comment: There are no tab bar in your layout...you only have view pager

Comment: Ok, in case when I created the project with tabbed activity ( before I removed the auto generated static Fragment inner class ) it was showing the tabs. At that time also there were no tabs anywhere but still automatically tabs were created.